# How can I bind only Left-Option to Meta/ESC in Terminal?

Tags: terminal

I need Option for typing some special characters, so I cannot use Terminal.app’s “Use Option as Meta key” setting. But I cannot bear to do without an ESC-emitting Meta key either.

Eventually I got around to trying out iTerm2, and discovered that it allows one to choose to treat only *one* of the Option keys as a +ESC key (I chose the left one), which is absolutely perfect and exactly what I was after.

But I’ve basically spent all my time with it so far making it more like Terminal.app. Literally the *only* feature I *like* is the Left-Option binding; everything else it does differently from Terminal.app, I *dis*like.

And it’s ugly. From the icon on down.

So I wonder, is there any way I could teach Terminal.app this trick, to bind only one of the Option keys as Meta, so that I can ditch iTerm2?

Answer (score 2):

There's probably a better way to do this, but you could try saving this as private.xml in [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<appdef>
<appname>APPLETERMINAL</appname>
<equal>com.apple.Terminal</equal>
</appdef>
<item>
<name>Terminal meta</name>
<identifier>private.terminal-meta</identifier>
<only>APPLETERMINAL</only>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::A, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::A</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::B, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::B</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::C, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::C</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::D, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::D</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::E, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::E</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::F</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::G, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::G</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::H, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::H</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::I, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::I</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::J, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::J</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::K, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::K</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::L, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::L</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::M, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::M</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::N, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::N</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::O, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::O</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::P, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::P</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::Q, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::Q</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::R, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::R</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::S, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::S</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::T, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::T</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::U, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::U</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::V, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::V</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::W, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::W</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::X, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::X</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::Y, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::Y</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::Z, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::Z</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_0, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEY_0</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_1, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEY_1</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_2, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEY_2</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_3, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEY_3</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_4, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEY_4</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_5, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEY_5</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_6, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEY_6</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_7, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEY_7</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_8, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEY_8</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_9, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEY_9</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::BACKQUOTE, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::BACKQUOTE</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::BACKSLASH, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::BACKSLASH</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::BRACKET_LEFT, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::BRACKET_LEFT</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::BRACKET_RIGHT, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::BRACKET_RIGHT</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::COMMA, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::COMMA</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::DOT, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::DOT</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::EQUAL, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::EQUAL</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::MINUS, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::MINUS</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::QUOTE, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::QUOTE</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::SEMICOLON, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::SEMICOLON</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::SLASH, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::SLASH</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEYPAD_0, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEYPAD_0</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEYPAD_1, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEYPAD_1</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEYPAD_2, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEYPAD_2</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEYPAD_3, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEYPAD_3</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEYPAD_4, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEYPAD_4</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEYPAD_5, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEYPAD_5</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEYPAD_6, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEYPAD_6</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEYPAD_7, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEYPAD_7</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEYPAD_8, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEYPAD_8</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEYPAD_9, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEYPAD_9</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEYPAD_CLEAR, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEYPAD_CLEAR</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEYPAD_COMMA, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEYPAD_COMMA</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEYPAD_DOT, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEYPAD_DOT</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEYPAD_EQUAL, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEYPAD_EQUAL</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEYPAD_MINUS, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEYPAD_MINUS</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEYPAD_MULTIPLY, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEYPAD_MULTIPLY</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEYPAD_PLUS, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEYPAD_PLUS</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEYPAD_SLASH, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEYPAD_SLASH</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::DELETE, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::DELETE</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::ENTER, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::ENTER</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::ESCAPE, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::ESCAPE</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::FORWARD_DELETE, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::FORWARD_DELETE</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RETURN, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::RETURN</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::SPACE, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::SPACE</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::TAB, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::TAB</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::CURSOR_UP, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::CURSOR_UP</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::CURSOR_DOWN, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::CURSOR_DOWN</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::PAGEUP, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::PAGEUP</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::PAGEDOWN, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::PAGEDOWN</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::HOME, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::HOME</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::END, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::END</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::UK_SECTION, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::UK_SECTION</autogen>
</item>
</root>
```

This wouldn't work with repeated key presses:

`__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::OPTION_L, KeyCode::VK_NONE, Option::KEYTOKEY_BEFORE_KEYDOWN, KeyCode::ESCAPE`

Comment: Wow, that’s one *spectacularly* ugly hack. :-)  I hope someone else shows up with a better idea! Though it’s at least a way to do it, so thanks for that.